# AngularJS Controller As Jasmine test with mock service with promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am creating a test for angular controller and I want to create a mock service that returns promise. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825798/how-do-i-mock-the-result-in-a-http-get-promise-when-testing-my-angularjs-contro) but this does not work with `Controller As`. Any idea how would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to get it working by injecting scope in the test although my controller doesn't inject code (bit wierd but that is how was done by a PluralSight toturial by John Papa).

So I can call call my method as `scope.controllerVM.doSomething();`

and then make a call to `scope.$digest()` to trigger call to the method